# python check for a valid email

Tags: python, email

Python Central published this [simple script](https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-python/) on the 29th December 2016 to check for a properly formatted email.

```
import re

def isValidEmail(email):
    if len(email) > 7:
        if re.match("^.+@([?)[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+.([a-zA-Z]{2,3}|[0-9]{1,3})(]?)$", email) != None:
            return True
        return False

if isValidEmail("my.email@gmail.com") == True:
    print("This is a valid email address")
else:
    print("This is not a valid email address")
```

While trying it, python 3 returned the following error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/isValidEmail.py", line 11, in <module>
    if isValidEmail("my.email@gmail.com") == True:
  File "~/isValidEmail.py", line 7, in isValidEmail
    if re.match("^.+@([?)[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+.([a-zA-Z]{2,3}|[0-9]{1,3})(]?)$", email) != None:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/re.py", line 163, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/re.py", line 293, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sre_compile.py", line 536, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sre_parse.py", line 829, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sre_parse.py", line 437, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sre_parse.py", line 781, in _parse
    source.tell() - start)
sre_constants.error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 4
```

How may I fix this error?

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce Thanks. The error msg went away after putting "\".

Comment: please validate your regex first here https://regex101.com/

Comment: @SunBear You should accept the answer if it really did solve your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closing bracket `)` is being included inside the square brackets because the square bracket before it isn't escaped properly.

```
^.+@([?)[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+.
     ^
     v
^.+@(\[?)[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+.
```

Example:

```
In[2]: import re
  ...: 
  ...: 
  ...: def is_valid_email(email):
  ...:     if len(email) > 7:
  ...:         return bool(re.match(
  ...:             "^.+@(\[?)[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+.([a-zA-Z]{2,3}|[0-9]{1,3})(]?)$", email))
  ...: 
In[3]: is_valid_email("my.email@gmail.com")
Out[3]: True
```